# countdown js not working on Angular 13 - Ionic 5. TypeError: countdown__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_14__ is not a function

Tags: typescript, ionic5, angular13, countdownjs.js

It seems that countdown.js does not work on my project built with Ionic 5 & Angular 13.

**Error: >TypeError: countdown__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_14__ is not a function.**

I'm migrating the code from an ionic 3 & angular 7 project in which countdown.js works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, after 12 hours of research I finally found a solution.

If you install countdown.js from `npm` you will install the `2.6.0` version. **BUT this is not the latest version**. The author did not update npm libraries.

Assuming you already installed the `2.6.0` version in your project you need to follow the following steps in order to get it to work in your Angular 13 project.

1. Edit the `countdown.js` file in `countdown`  folder, inside
   your `node_modules` folder:

   Replace all the code of your `countdown.js` file copy/pasting
   the code from [this file in
   GitHub](https://github.com/mckamey/countdownjs/blob/master/countdown.js).
2. Edit the `package.json` file in `countdown`  folder, inside
   your `node_modules` folder.

   Replace every single

   `2.6.0`

   by

   `2.6.1`
3. Edit the `package.json` project level file:

   Replace

   `"countdown": "^2.6.0"`

   by

   `"countdown": "2.6.1"`

This is it! Countdown.js should work now in your Angular 13 project. (It worked for me)